# If a poset does not have any infinite descending chains it is well-founded

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

My professor told me “If and only if a poset does not have any infinite descending chains it is well-founded” . And PO relations are reflexive and in (x,x):  x is a Predecessor for x then we have a descending chain like x,x,x,x,x,... 
I’m confused by the definition. Should we ignore all (x,x) elements like what we do in minimal definition ?

Comment: Here "infinite descending chain" means an infinite chain decreasing *strictly*, so yes, we must rule out the reflective case.

Comment: Thank you  